# How do I combine select rows into a new row within my query

Tags: mysql

I am very new to coding in general, so please excuse any basic mistakes in my syntax or knowledge. I am using a query that I didn't write, but that I am trying to improve.

```
set @year = 2020;
set @reportd = '###';
set @asofday = '2020-01-01';

select format(sum(x.value), 0) xvalue, x.ptype
    from
        ( select p.mnum, (p.bvalue + p.lvalue) as value,
        p.exeamount, p.excamount,
        p.damount, phis.ptype
        from history h
            join Dfee d
            on d.p_id = h.p_id
            and d.dcode = @reportd
                join( select max(history.id) as id,
                pc.ptype
                from history
                join cash c on history.id = c.p_id
                join pclass pc on history.pc_id = pc.id
                where c.year = @year
                and date(c.cdate) <= (select x.date
                    from (select date(cdate) date,
                    count(date(cdate)) A
                    from cash
                    where year = @year
                    group by date(cdate)
                    having A > 1
                    order by A desc
                    limit 1) x)
                    group by history.mnum ) phis.id = h.id) x
                    group by x.ptype ;
```

What this gives me is two columns and 4 rows

```
   +------------+------------+
   |      xvalue|    ptype   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 124,213,122|      home  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 223,334,552|      work  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 112,112,220|      away  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 154,556,454|     lunch  |
   +------------+------------+
```

What I am trying to do is to combine two of the rows into one under a new name. I can't alter the database in any way, so this all has to be within the query if possible.
Below is what I would like it to return. I want to combine the rows of 'away' and 'lunch' into a total sum of the two.

```
   +------------+------------+
   |      xvalue|    ptype   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 124,213,122|      home  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 223,334,552|      work  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 266,668,674|       afk  |
   +------------+------------+
```

If I add this

```
     , SUM(xvalue) xvalue  
  FROM 
     ( [YOUR QUERY HERE] ) x
 GROUP 
    BY xtype;
```

Then my query returns

```
   | xvalue| ptype |
   +-------+-------+
   | 124   | home  |
   +-------+-------+
   | 223   | work  |
   +-------+-------+
   | 112   | afk   |
   +-------+-------+
   | 154   | afk   |
   +-------+-------+
```

FIXED AND UPDATED

```
set @year = 2020;
set @reportd = '###';
set @asofday = '2020-01-01';

select (case when y.ptype in('Work', 'Home') then y.ptype else 'Afk' end) ptype, format(sum(xvalue), 0) yvalue
from (
 select format(sum(x.value), 0) xvalue, x.ptype
    from
        ( select p.mnum, (p.bvalue + p.lvalue) as value,
        p.exeamount, p.excamount,
        p.damount, phis.ptype
        from history h
            join Dfee d
            on d.p_id = h.p_id
            and d.dcode = @reportd
                join( select max(history.id) as id,
                pc.ptype
                from history
                join cash c on history.id = c.p_id
                join pclass pc on history.pc_id = pc.id
                where c.year = @year
                and date(c.cdate) <= (select x.date
                    from (select date(cdate) date,
                    count(date(cdate)) A
                    from cash
                    where year = @year
                    group by date(cdate)
                    having A > 1
                    order by A desc
                    limit 1) x)
                    group by history.mnum ) phis.id = h.id) x
                    group by x.ptype) y
                    group by ptype;
```

This correctly joined and sumed the two rows into a new one.

```
+------------+------------+
   |      xvalue|    ptype   |
   +------------+------------+
   | 124,213,122|      home  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 223,334,552|      work  |
   +------------+------------+
   | 266,668,674|      afk   |
   +------------+------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I believe that you want me to provide a reproductible example, but seeing as how complex this is I don't really see how I can simplify it any. I'm sorry if I have done something incorrect.

Comment: I have faith in you.

Comment: Lol. I'm glad that you have faith it me. I have cut some more from it. If I need to simplify it further please let me know. And I do appreciate your help. I want to be able to use your site correctly

Comment: Why do you list `p.exeamount *  exeamount` twice? And why qualify some columns and not others?

Comment: Also, perhaps it was an error of concision, but this bit makes no sense: `) phis.id = h.id`

Comment: I have further cut it down. ```p.exeamount``` and ```p.excamount``` are two different columns. I qualify the columns that I have to so they aren't ambiguous as many of the tables share column names.

Comment: It's good practice to qualify ALL columns, It greatly aids readability when you come to review what you wrote months later.

Comment: I agree completely. Unfortunately I didn't write this query, it was written by the person in the job before me, and it and many of the other queries that were left are very difficult to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ptype NOT IN('home','work') THEN 'afk' ELSE ptype END  xtype
 -- or CASE WHEN ptype IN('home','work') THEN ptype ELSE 'afk' END  xtype
     , SUM(xvalue) xvalue  
  FROM 
     ( [YOUR QUERY HERE] ) x
 GROUP 
    BY xtype;
```

Would ouput...

```
+-------+-----------+
| xtype | xvalue    |
+-------+-----------+
| afk   | 266668674 |
| home  | 124213122 |
| work  | 223334552 |
+-------+-----------+
```

If you want the formatting (bad idea), just move the formatting to this new superquery

Comment: Doing this correctly renames the two rows I want to rename, but it doesn't combine them, and it cuts down the value to just the digits before the first comma.

Comment: So for example, 1,000,000 being 1, and 121,122,000 being 121.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by it being a bad idea, but you were right. Removing the formatting returned the values to their correct value.

Comment: I fixed it. I was trying to group by ``` x.ptype ```. grouping instead by ``` ptype ``` correctly joined the two rows. You're a saint. I had been stuck on this for two days

Comment: Yep - that's an annoying idiosyncrasy of aliases that can sometimes occur. I wonder if I've done enough to get an upvote